# SCP filename tab completion

Tags: linux, ssh, command-line-interface, mac-osx, scp

I use SCP regularly to move files between servers and I've heard rumoured that you can use tab-completion on the remote server if you're using public keys, but so far I have had no luck.

What I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

```
scp -r remote.ip.address:/remote/dir/folder<TAB> /local/destiation/
```

An `ls` on the remote server of `/dir/` would reveal 3 folders:

```
/remote/dir/folder_1
/remote/dir/folder_2
/remote/dir/folder_3
```

I'd like for SCP to reveal which folders match (if any), just like normal path completion when navigating the local filesystem. Tab completion does work on the local paths in the `scp` command line, but I've noticed that when the path for the remote machine matches the local (ie: "~/"), it completes/suggests files/folders from the local filesystem rather than the remote.

Running the following works for password-less login:

```
`ssh remote.ip.address`
```

...so I know the keys are setup correctly. Any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: Just used this - omgbbq

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Which shell are you using? If you are using bash you may need to 
enable "advanced" completions in bash...

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

In your ~/.bashrc

On OSX you can do:

```
$ sudo port install bash-completion
```

To your  ~/.profile add:

```
if [ -f /opt/local/etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /opt/local/etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Comment: I'm using OSX as a workstation, that file doesn't exist.  However, I'm assuming that with any distrubtion I need to install the bash-completion package to get this to work?

Comment: I will update my answer..

Comment: I just finished going through those steps myself, all works well. Thanks mate!

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Comment: Of course, the port install part for OS X only works, if you have installed the MacPorts package (www.macports.org). And I guess there is package available if you should use fink instead of MacPorts.

Comment: Are there any downsides to enabling the "advanced" completions?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is wanting to do this for Mac OSX Mountain Lion with rkthkr's method, they have to install Mac Ports (http://www.macports.org/install.php) first, run the command he mentioned:

```
$ sudo port install bash-completion
```

then configure their terminal app per these instructions found here: https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/bash-completion

Comment: When you have enough reputation to leave comments, additions to existing answers usually work better with those. (if you aren't going to edit the answers)

Comment: Thanks. That's what I wanted to do but, as you mentioned, I didn't have enough rep to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Another, maybe simpler solution is using [*sshfs*](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html).

> This is a file system client based on the SSH File Transfer Protocol. Since most SSH servers already support this protocol it is very easy to set up: i.e. on the server side there's nothing to do.  On the client side mounting the filesystem is as easy as logging into the server with ssh.

It's a *fuse* based file system which links your remote folder to a local one. Under the hood, scp is used, but you can operate the `cp` command just like copying files on your local machine. Thus, **tab-completion** works automatically! *sshfs* is available for most distributions, e.g. do `sudo apt-get install sshfs` (this also loads the `fuse` kernel module)

Start like this:

```
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/server1
$ sudo chown local-username /mnt/server1
$ sshfs remote-username@server1.example.com:/home/remote-username /mnt/server1
$ ls /mnt/server1
 .. <bunch of files> ...
$ cp /mnt/server1/.bash<tab><tab>
.bash_history  .bash_logout   .bashrc
$ cp /mnt/server1/.bashrc .
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using [yafc](http://yafc.sourceforge.net/).

It supports filename completion and has some other useful features as well (eg recursive get/put/fxp/ls/rm)