# Disable networked tab completion with bash

Tags: linux, networking, bash, command-line-interface

Networked applications like **rsync** and **scp** can tab complete when they are [enabled](https://serverfault.com/questions/26768/scp-filename-tab-completion) with bash. But what if you want local tab completion without remote tab completion? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a Red Hat/CentOS-style system, you can remove the bash-completion for a specific application by navigating to `/etc/bash_completion.d/` and removing the entry (symbolic link) that corresponds to the command...

```
[root@xt /etc/bash_completion.d]# ls -l
total 132
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    38 Oct  4  2011 _subversion -> /usr/share/bash-completion/_subversion
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    31 Oct  4  2011 _yum -> /usr/share/bash-completion/_yum
.
.
.  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    32 Oct  4  2011 rsync -> /usr/share/bash-completion/rsync
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    32 Oct  4  2011 samba -> /usr/share/bash-completion/samba
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    33 Oct  4  2011 screen -> /usr/share/bash-completion/screen
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    34 Oct  4  2011 sqlite3 -> /usr/share/bash-completion/sqlite3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    30 Oct  4  2011 ssh -> /usr/share/bash-completion/ssh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    33 Oct  4  2011 strace -> /usr/share/bash-completion/strace
```

Also, it seems that `complete -r commandname` can also work.

Edit: 
You can also edit the bash completion entries for a particular service. For instance, in `scp`, you can comment out the references to the `_scp_remote_files` function to give local folder completion without expanding remote filesystems...

Comment: This seems like a semi-decent solution, but could get tedious with many different applications installed. Newly installed applications would have to be taken into account too. Isn't there a better way? Considering that all the applications define their own completion I suppose it's impossible.

Comment: `complete -r commandname` is probably the best bet.